# Convert a string to a list of dictionaries

Tags: ansible, yaml

In a file named test.yml, I have a variable:

```
ACTIONS: "[{a: '123', b: '1'}, {a: '456', b: '2'}]"
```

I call it in another file:

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - test.yml
  tasks:
    - name: Set var
      set_fact:
        test: "{{ ACTIONS }}"

    - name: Display var
      debug:
        msg: "{{ test | type_debug }}"
```

I have tried with split, items2dict, map and lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string to YAML. Use the filter *from_yaml*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        test: "{{ ACTIONS|from_yaml }}"
```

You get the list of dictionaries

```yaml
  test:
  - a: '123'
    b: '1'
  - a: '456'
    b: '2'
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: localhost

  vars_files:
    - test.yml

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: ACTIONS|type_debug
    - debug:
        var: ACTIONS

    - set_fact:
        test: "{{ ACTIONS|from_yaml }}"

    - debug:
        var: test|type_debug
    - debug:
        var: test
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml 

PLAY [localhost] *****************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ACTIONS|type_debug: AnsibleUnicode

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  ACTIONS: '[{a: ''123'', b: ''1''}, {a: ''456'', b: ''2''}]'

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  test|type_debug: list

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  test:
  - a: '123'
    b: '1'
  - a: '456'
    b: '2'

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
localhost: ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Sorry but it didn't work. I have a unicode string error.

Comment: It works for me. I have no errors.